# How to send a JSON and an image file to a server?

Tags: angularjs, spring, server

I am trying to send a JSON file and an image file together to a server, but am really struggling.

1) If I send just the quilt item, so skipping the formData and changing the $http part below to $http.post('quilts/create/', quilt), then set the server end point to expect (@RequestBody QuiltRequest quiltRequest) without the bits about transformRequest and headers, it processes the data therein quite happily but I don't have an image to add to the records.

2) If I don't add the quilt item to the formData, and tell the server to expect (@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image), I can save the image file on my server and generate a url string for it, but have no other quilt information to make the corresponding database entry.

How can I send both the quilt and the image in one request, and have the server receive and process both?

Many thanks!

Client-side service:

```
this.create = function (quilt, image) {
        quilt.size = JSON.parse(quilt.size);
        quilt.maker = JSON.parse(quilt.maker);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('quiltRequest', quilt);
        formData.append('image', image);
        $http.post('quilts/create/', formData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).then(function (response) {
            return window.location = '#!/quilts/created/' + response.data;
        })
    };
```

Server-side end point:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/create")
    public BigInteger create(@RequestPart QuiltRequest quiltRequest, @RequestPart MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        // do stuff based on parameters received
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart of it, i think you can try to encode the image to base64 string. Send it to server and at the server, You decode it

Answer (score 0):

My required solution have given by a real-world hero, and is posted here in case anyone else with a similar problem stumbles upon this thread :)  (But thank you to user3562932 for taking some time to read and make a suggestion).

On the client side, we have moved the five lines of data preparation into a separate method, such that the original create() now takes a bunch of parameters and jumps straight to $http.post(url, *data which has been magically transformed into something appropriate to send* {rules on how to send the data}).

```
        $http.post('quilts/create/', formData(quilt, image), {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).then(function (response) {
            return window.location = '#!/quilts/created/' + response.data;
        })
```

The magical transformation happens in new function formData(), which takes as its parameters the data we want to send and makes the necessary changes:
1) make a formData container for the data to be POSTed.
2) stringify information from the html form (e.g. text, numbers) into a JSON and append to formData.
2a) in this particular case, my quilt structure contains size and maker details which arrived from the backend as JSONs, and were selected in the webpage from drop-down lists of various sizes and makers, hence the parsing rows to get these items ready to be included in the formData.
3) convert files into BLOBs, and then likewise append.
4) return formData, with all required information neatly wrapped up and ready to go!
Note: in the services.js file, this formData() method actually appears above the create() method, but it feels more logical to talk about them this way around.

```
function formData(quilt, image) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        quilt.size = JSON.parse(quilt.size);
        quilt.maker = JSON.parse(quilt.maker);
        formData.append('quiltRequest', JSON.stringify(quilt));
        formData.append('image', new Blob([image]));
        return formData;
    }
```

On the server side, we can now happily receive this through:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/create", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public BigInteger create(@RequestParam(value = "quiltRequest") String quiltRequest,
                             @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        QuiltRequest quilt = new ObjectMapper().readValue(quiltRequest, QuiltRequest.class);
        QuiltResponse quiltResponse = quiltService.create(quilt, image);
        return quiltResponse.getQuilt().getId();
    }
```

In order to enable the end point to consume our exciting multimedia input, we have to add the following import at the top of the class:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
```

We use another import to enable the use of the MultipartFile class that we have designated for the incoming image file:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
```

The JSON object from the webpage has come through as a String, but that needs to be parsed into its underlying components to actually be of use.  This is where the ObjectMapper comes into play.  Call on its readValue() method, and pass in the string argument plus a template of what the information should look like when unwrapped (here, a QuiltRequest class with defined properties corresponding to the information we fed into the JSON back in the client-end server).  Remember to include the necessary import to access the ObjectMapper:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Hopefully this breakdown of the changes makes sense, with enough explanation to help other developers build end-to-end POST requests to suit their own projects.